# How to disable NUnit Adapter for given project?

Tags: c#, nunit

Since I've installed NUnit Adapter, for all projects, even if NUnit is not used, discovery process is still taking place.

```
------ Discover test started ------
NUnit Adapter 3.2.0.0: Test discovery starting
Exception NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException, Exception thrown discovering tests in I:\src\...
Cannot run tests in process - a 32 bit process is required.
NUnit Adapter 3.2.0.0: Test discovery complete
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.1180118) ==========
```

How can I disable NUnit from discovering tests for given project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure that all test adapters that you have installed run for all assemblies every time you build, NUnit is just a bit more verbose about it which is very annoying.

Tests won't be discovered though if the **Test Explorer** window is not open. Unfortunately, closing the window isn't enough, you need to close it, then restart Visual Studio.

**Update:** Based on the comments, also make sure that **Keep Test Execution Engine Running** is not checked.

---

The following is on my system running Visual Studio 2015 Update 2;

Test Explorer Window Closed, Rebuild All;

[image: No tests in output]

Notice, no test discovery or Test in the dropdown. You can also see in the **Test | Test Settings** that the test engine is not running because the menu options are disabled.

[image: Tests not running]

As soon as I open **Test Explorer** however;

[image: Tests now in output]

Even if I close the window, tests continue to be discovered until I restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Test Explorer is closed all the time. However, what is most annoying, is that every time I build a project, the Output pane is switching from current selected "Show output from" to "Tests".

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: Same as yours - Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Comment: And you are sure Test Explorer is closed, not just unpinned? And you have restarted VS? Typical developer response, but "it works on my computer" :)

Comment: I added another screenshot showing the test menu. I assume yours is enabled after a VS restart?

Comment: You can also check to make sure that Visual Studio hasn't added the following to your CSPROJ file. It indicates that it is a test project and usually gets added near the end.


  `<ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{82A7F48D-3B50-4B1E-B82E-3ADA8210C358}" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: Typical blindness of mine. The "Keep Test Execution Engine Running" was ticked.

Comment: One thing to note, the 32 bit process exception is a bug in NUnit that will be fixed soon.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, it can be very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017
Go to Tools-> Extensions and updates-> Find your Nunit adapter and click on disable

[image: NUnit adapter (disabled)]